# Find an orth0normal basis for the null space and the range of the following matrix:

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Looking for hints to find the orthnormal basis for the null space/range of the following matrix

$A = \frac{1}{3}\left( \begin{array}{ccc}
2 & -1 & -1 \\
-1 & 2 & -1 \\
-1 & -1 & 2 \end{array} \right)$

Comment: Solve $Ax=0$ to find the null space.  The column space is the range -- so find a basis for the column space.

Answer (score 0):

*Hint.* Note that
$$
\DeclareMathOperator{rref}{rref}\rref (A)
=
\begin{bmatrix}
1&0&-1\\0&1&-1\\0&0&0
\end{bmatrix}
$$
Since $A\vec x=\vec 0$ if and only if $\rref(A)\vec x=\vec 0$, it follows that $A\vec x=\vec 0$ if and only if
$$
\vec x=
\begin{bmatrix}
x_1\\x_2\\x_3
\end{bmatrix}
=\begin{bmatrix}x_3\\x_3\\x_3\end{bmatrix}
=x_3\begin{bmatrix}1\\1\\1\end{bmatrix}
$$
Hence $\{\langle1,1,1\rangle\}$ is a basis for the nullspace of $A$.

To find an orthogonal basis for the columnspace of $A$, note that $\rref(A)$ tells us $\DeclareMathOperator{rank}{rank}\rank(A)=2$. That is, the columnspace has dimension two and a basis is given by the columns of $A$ that correspond to the pivot columns in $\rref(A)$. Hence the columns of 
$$
A_c=
\begin{bmatrix}
2&-1\\-1&2\\-1&-1
\end{bmatrix}
$$ 
Form a basis for the columnspace of $A$. Do you know how to make this basis into an orthonormal basis?

Comment: Thanks! Can you elaborate on the last part. How come the basis is given by the columns of A that correspond to the pivot columns?

Answer (score 0):

In this case after a few row operations on $A\vec{x}=\vec{0}$, you will find out that $\operatorname{rank}(A)=2$. By the rank-nullity theorem, $\operatorname{nullity}(A)=1$, so the null space of $A$ will have dimension $1$. Finding out the relation between $x$,$y$, and $z$ gives a column vector $(1,1,1)^T$ as a basis of the null space. To make it a unit vector, divide it by $\sqrt{3}$.